# I can't use a variable in createFormBuilder

Tags: forms, symfony-forms, symfony

Why I can't use my variable $idType in my function createFormBuilder ?

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $idType = $options['data']->getEvenement()->getType()->getId();

    $builder
        ->add('depart',      DateTimeType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text'
        ))
        ->add('inscription', TextType::class)
        ->add('prixNl',      IntegerType::class)
        ->add('prixL',       IntegerType::class)
        ->add('resultat',    TextType::class)
        ->add('sousType',     EntityType::class, array(
            'class'        => 'CalendrierBundle:SousType',
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'multiple'     => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.typeId = :type')
                    ->setParameter('type', $idType);
            }
        ))
        ->add('save',        SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```

She is don't recognize

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suggest adding little bit more verbiage to explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `use ($idType)` keyword to inherit $idType variable from the parent scope into the [closure](http://php.net/manual/functions.anonymous.php).

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $idType = $options['data']->getEvenement()->getType()->getId();

    $builder
        ->add('depart',      DateTimeType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text'
        ))
        ->add('inscription', TextType::class)
        ->add('prixNl',      IntegerType::class)
        ->add('prixL',       IntegerType::class)
        ->add('resultat',    TextType::class)
        ->add('sousType',     EntityType::class, array(
            'class'        => 'CalendrierBundle:SousType',
            'choice_label' => 'nom',
            'multiple'     => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($idType) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.typeId = :type')
                    ->setParameter('type', $idType);
            }
        ))
        ->add('save',        SubmitType::class)
    ;
}
```